# Recreate object in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have simple issue: need recreate a object with other parameters.
Have this object:

```
object NetworkClient {
    var BASE_URL = "http://google.ru" //we can take this from another class or Pref's
    const val API_BASE_URL = "$BASE_URL/api/"

    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    val client: Client
    var retrofit: Retrofit

    init {    
        val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

        retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build()
        client = retrofit.create<PapaJobsClient>(Client::class.java)
    }
}
```

In rare cases you need to change the BASE_URL on the fly to another String and recreate client and etc. I know how to make it, but my resolution so hard - need rework all places where i use this class but i want create this object with concrete parameter. How you think about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a separate class for that, since singletons (`object` in Kotlin) cannot have a constructor:

```
class NetworkClient(val baseUrl: String) {
    const val API_BASE_URL = "$baseUrl/api/"

    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    val client: Client
    var retrofit: Retrofit

    init {    
       // ...
    }
}
```

Use an `object` to have the current networkClient instance always at hand:

```
object NetworkClientProvider {
    var networkClient = NetworkClient("http://google.ru")
}
```

Usage, if you need to create a new `NetworkClient`:

```
NetworkClientProvider.networkClient = NetworkClient("http://someOtherDomain.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing `object` here. This should be used if you really have a **single** instance of a class, it's the Kotlin built-in feature for applying the *Singleton* pattern.

Fix it by making it a regular class:

```
class NetworkClient(val baseurl: String) {
    const val API_BASE_URL = "$baseurl/api/"

    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    //...

}
```

Then it’s possible to create objects with different `baseurl`s as shown:

```
val russian = NetworkClient("http://google.ru")
val com = NetworkClient("http://google.com")
```

Comment: he wants to have only one instance of the network client at a time, so he is not misusing object as much as you are implying.